# Accuracy of unix utc epoch time in seconds in java

Tags: java

I have seen people using System.currentTimeInMillis and converting it into seconds to store unix utc epoch time. But in Java 8 we can also use Instant.ofEpochSeconds. Which one is more accurate? Is it better to use Instant.ofEpochMillis and convert it into seconds for better accuracy ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, [`Instant.ofEpochSecond(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-) takes an argument and is used to represent an `Instant`. I think you meant [`Instant.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--) which says (in part)

> This will query the [system UTC clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#systemUTC--) to obtain the current instant.

And, [system UTC clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#systemUTC--) says (in part)

> This may use [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--), or a higher resolution clock if one is available.

So the answer is, it depends. But calling [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) which (per the Javadoc) *returns*

> the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

**Note** that unix epoch is in seconds.

Comment: so which one should I use ?

Comment: Seems like that's going to be opinion, but really what are you trying to do? A high precision clock may or may not be available.